# How to make button bright when clicking (like clicking shift key in iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uikeyboard

I want to do a shift key. When I click it, the key will change to other letters. How can I make it bright when clicking this shift button like in iphone ? Can you give some example codes ?

Comment: sorry! I just try to search in here and there is no question related, so I ask if there is quick help.

Comment: @Superman We really need to learn how to use down-votes properly. People are abusing this property.

Comment: @OhhMee downvote for less effort in searching,this problem can be easily search in the google.

Comment: sorry, when I search, the result is not clear, so I ask others here ! You can downvote as you can, but you should understand others' problems !

Comment: @Superman Yep, that's what I'm talking. See the person below, he answered her and now she understood it all. That's how things work. Down-votes are discouraging. People come with different skill levels and sometimes they are at beginner level (even with the search skills). Are we too greedy that we know everything and we can't help a person? I'm seeing increase in down-votes these days.

Comment: @OhhMee +1 for that. I support completely support you these down votes  and negative comments are very discouraging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like a button's image to change when tapped, and then back, you can use the -[setImage:forState:] method.  For this example, imagine yourself having 2 images: image_one.png and image_two.png for the unpressed and pressed images respectively.

Suppose you have a button like so:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_one.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[self view] addSubview:button];
```

You can add a target and action that will change the image back and forth.  To see which image it is currently, I'd use the tag property.

```
[button setTag:0]; // initial, non pressed button tag, for this example
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(swapImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And have something like the following in the setImage method:

```
-(void)swapImage:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([sender tag] == 0) {

        [sender setTag:1]; // pressed tag, for example
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_two.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        [sender setTag:0]; // non-pressed tag, for example
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_one.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

When you first tap the button, it selects.  Tapping it another time will unselect it - just like the keyboard's shift button.

Comment: Yes, you will have an image for the pressed and un-pressed state.  In the above code, they are referred to as image_one.png and image_two.png

Comment: after testing the code above, it works well! Thank you again 

Aaron Wojnowski!  @chhanmalin the code above  is the answer you want !